# How to create a word document icon or button in WORDPRESS, when clicked, a word document whose content is created using php code will be downloaded?

Tags: php, wordpress, ms-word, elementor, code-snippets

I have a WordPress application with a lot of pages that are created using codes that I wrote in PHP and are inserted into the pages using PHP-code-snippet.

Now I want to create a 'newsletter' (bulletin) on a separate page, there will be a button or a Word icon whose content will be individual parts from other pages in the application.

I realized that the only solution is to write a PHP code and somehow insert it into that WORD content. I need a Word document (not a pdf) because users will later be able to insert some pictures of the sponsor at the end of the document.

I didn't find any plugin for this; Maybe one of you knows something?

Or I have an idea to simply display that content in one section on the page (using the code from the snippet) and somehow insert a section below where users can upload pictures of sponsors, and then on that page there is some 'Word' or even 'PDF' (if is there image upload) button - and to generate a word document when clicked, with the content of those two sections?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to generate a document in php (in this case a text document), save it to a file in the tempdocs subfolder, then re-direct the client to it is shown with the following naive script.

```
<?php

  $filename = (rand() %1000000).(rand() %1000000).".txt";
  if(file_put_contents("tempdocs/".$filename, "Time is ".time()."\n") === false) {
    echo "Error Saving File.";
  } else {
    header("Location: /tempdocs/".$filename);
  }

?>
```

If you want your users to be able to make alterations to the document, then that is a much less trivial undertaking with security issues to consider. I suggest you find a way for your users to upload images and text to your database then generate the Word document dynamically from the database.

A document saved this way is public and can be viewed by anyone who knows its URL. If you want only logged in users to be able to view the document, then again, that is much less trivial.